# Load SpreadJS using jsdom and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom, spreadjs, grapecity

I am trying to load SpreadJS using Jsdom, But it is giving error: **need a browser which full supports HTML5 Canvas to run SpreadJS**.

Where as jsom **[doc](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#canvas-support)** says it supports canvas.

I have installed [canvas-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-prebuilt) for jsom.

This is the code I have done so far:

> index.js

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const options = {
    resources: 'usable',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
};

JSDOM.fromFile('index.html', options).then((dom) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(dom.window.document.body.textContent.trim());
    }, 1000);
});
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SpreadJS ExcelIO</title>
    <script src="libs/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="libs/gc.spread.sheets.excel2013white.10.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/gc.spread.sheets.all.10.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/gc.spread.excelio.10.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var workbook = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("ss"));
            var worksheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
            worksheet.getCell(3,3).value("SpreadJS");
            worksheet.getCell(5,5).value("SpreadJS");
            worksheet.getCell(7,7).value("SpreadJS");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ss" style="height:600px ; width :100%; ">sss</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the code slightly to get the Spread object or the information in it.

index.html:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var workbook = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("ss"));
        var worksheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
        worksheet.getCell(3,3).value("SpreadJS");
        worksheet.getCell(5,5).value("SpreadJS");
        worksheet.getCell(7,7).value("SpreadJS");
        window.workbook = workbook;
    });
```

index.js:

```
JSDOM.fromFile('index.html', options).then((dom) => {
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(dom.window.workbook.getActiveSheet().getCell(3,3).value());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Not able to get `workbook` object in `dom.window`.. Getting this error  **Cannot read property 'getActiveSheet' of undefined**

Comment: You will need to use the canvas package, as SpreadJS uses the canvas.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas